# Relação One-To-Many com nome da foreign key explícito

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, fluent-api

Estou realizando um mapeamento simples de *one-to-many* via Fluent API especificando qual é a coluna utilizada no mapeamento, porém, o EF "ignora" a configuração e continua utilizando o nome *default*.

Mapeamentos:

```
        public AtividadeMap()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.Codigo);

            ToTable("tb_atividade");

            Property(a => a.TituloAtividade).HasColumnName("titulo_atividade");
            Property(a => a.DescricaoAtividade).HasColumnName("descricao_atividade");
            Property(a => a.DataHoraInicio).HasColumnName("data_hora_inicio");
            Property(a => a.DataHoraFim).HasColumnName("data_hora_fim");
            Property(a => a.Codigo).HasColumnName("pk_atividade");
            Property(a => a.StatusAtividade.Identificador).HasColumnName("status_atividade");
            Property(a => a.EstimativaInicialAtividade).HasColumnName("estimativa_inicial_atividade");
            Property(a => a.TipoAtividade.Identificador).HasColumnName("tipo_atividade");

            HasRequired(a => a.Usuario)
           .WithMany()
           .Map(e => e.MapKey("fk_usuario"));

            HasRequired(a => a.Projeto)
           .WithMany()
           .Map(e => e.MapKey("fk_projeto"));

        }


        public ProjetoMap()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.Codigo);

            ToTable("tb_projeto");

            Property(p => p.Codigo).HasColumnName("pk_projeto");
            Property(a => a.Nome).HasColumnName("nome");
        }
```

Exceção:

[image: Exceção]

Como observado, o SQL está realizando uma busca por `CodigoProjeto` e `CodigoUsuario` ao invés de `fk_projeto` e `fk_usuario`

Além da exceção, uma dúvida: preciso mapear este *one-to-many* também nas classes da agregação (Projeto e Usuario)?

Se possível, preferiria mapear apenas na classe que consome a entidade, visando o isolamento da responsabilidade apenas para esta classe.

---

---- EDIT : Inclusão dos models relacionados ao problema ------

```
    public class Atividade : ObjetoPersistente
    {
        public Atividade()
        {
            Projeto = new Projeto();
            StatusAtividade = EStatusAtividade.NaoIniciado;
            TipoAtividade = ETipoAtividade.NovaImplementacao;
            Usuario = new Usuario();
        }       

        public DateTime DataHoraFim { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataHoraInicio { get; set; }

        public string DescricaoAtividade { get; set; }
        public string EstimativaInicialAtividade { get; set; }
        public Projeto Projeto { get; set; }

        public long CodigoProjeto 
        {
            get
            {
                return Projeto.Codigo;
            }
            set
            {
                Projeto.Codigo = value;
            }
        }

        public string NomeProjeto
        {
            get { return Projeto.Nome; }
        }

        public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

        public string LoginUsuario
        {
            get { return Usuario.Login; }
        }

        public long CodigoUsuario 
        {
            get
            {
                if(Usuario == null) Usuario = new Usuario();
                return Usuario.Codigo;
            }
            set
            {
                Usuario.Codigo = value;
            }
        }

        public EStatusAtividade StatusAtividade { get; set; }

        public string DescricaoStatusAtividade
        {
            get { return StatusAtividade.Descricao; }
        }           

        public string DescricaoTipoAtividade
        {
            get { return TipoAtividade.Descricao; }
        }

        public ETipoAtividade TipoAtividade { get; set; }
        public string TituloAtividade { get; set; }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj is Atividade) && (obj as Atividade).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Codigo.GetHashCode();
        }
    }


    public class Projeto : ObjetoPersistente, IObjetoElementoOption
    {       
        public string Nome { get; set; }                

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj is Projeto) && (obj as Projeto).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Codigo.GetHashCode();
        }

        public string Valor
        {
            get { return Codigo.ToString(); }
        }

        public string Descricao 
        {
            get { return Nome; }
        }
    }

    public class Usuario : ObjetoPersistente
    {       
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj is Usuario) && (obj as Usuario).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Codigo.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class ObjetoPersistente : IObjetoPersistente
    {
        public long Codigo { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj is ObjetoPersistente) && (obj as ObjetoPersistente).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Codigo.GetHashCode();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtêm lista de longos a partir dos códigos dos objetos persistentes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lista"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<long> ObtenhaListaDeCodigosPorListaDeObjetos<T>(List<T> lista) where T:ObjetoPersistente
        {
            var listaLongo = new List<long>();

            foreach (var objetoPersistente in lista)
            {
                listaLongo.Add(objetoPersistente.Codigo);
            }

            return listaLongo;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtêm lista de objetos do tipo genérico a partir de lista de códigos
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="listaDeCodigos"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<T> ObtenhaListaDeObjetoPorListaDeCodigos<T>(List<long> listaDeCodigos) where T  : ObjetoPersistente
        {
            var listaObjeto = new List<T>();

            foreach (var codigo in listaDeCodigos)
            {
                var objeto = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                objeto.Codigo = codigo;

                listaObjeto.Add(objeto);
            }

            return listaObjeto;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtêm objetos persistentes da lista que possuem a propriedade Código equivalente a 0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="objetos"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<T> ObtenhaObjetosComCodigoZerado<T>(List<T> objetos) where T : ObjetoPersistente
        {
            var resultado = new List<T>();

            foreach (var objeto in objetos)
            {
                if(objeto.Codigo.Equals(0))
                    resultado.Add(objeto);
            }

            return resultado;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtêm objetos persistentes da lista que possuem a propriedade Código diferente de 0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="objetos"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<T> ObtenhaObjetosComCodigoDiferenteDeZero<T>(List<T> objetos) where T : ObjetoPersistente
        {
            var resultado = new List<T>();

            foreach (var objeto in objetos)
            {
                if (!objeto.Codigo.Equals(0))
                    resultado.Add(objeto);
            }

            return resultado;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compara duas listas de objetos persistentes
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="listaBase"></param>
        /// <param name="listaAnalisada"></param>
        /// <returns>Os objetos persistentes da 'listaAnalisada' que não existem na 'listaBase'</returns>
        public static List<T> ObtenhaDiferenteEntreListas<T>(List<T> listaBase, List<T> listaAnalisada)
            where T : ObjetoPersistente
        {
            var resultado = new List<T>();

            foreach (var objetoPersistente in listaAnalisada)
            {
                if(!listaBase.Contains(objetoPersistente))
                    resultado.Add(objetoPersistente);
            }

            return resultado;
        }
    }
```

---

---- EDIT2 : Detalhes sobre o momento em que a exception é disparada ----

A exception ocorre no momento que realizo um 'find' no DbSet:

```
_dbContext.Set<Atividade>.Find(codigoItem);
```

O SQL que o EF produziu foi este:

```
SELECT "Alias1"."status_atividade", "Alias1"."pk_atividade", "Alias1"."data_hora_fim", "Alias1"."data_hora_inicio", "Alias1"."descricao_atividade", "Alias1"."estimativa_inicial_atividade", "Alias1"."CodigoProjeto", "Alias1"."CodigoUsuario", "Alias1"."tipo_atividade", "Alias1"."titulo_atividade", "Alias1"."fk_projeto", "Alias1"."fk_usuario" FROM (SELECT "Extent1"."pk_atividade", "Extent1"."data_hora_fim", "Extent1"."data_hora_inicio", "Extent1"."descricao_atividade", "Extent1"."estimativa_inicial_atividade", "Extent1"."CodigoProjeto", "Extent1"."CodigoUsuario", "Extent1"."status_atividade", "Extent1"."tipo_atividade", "Extent1"."titulo_atividade", "Extent1"."fk_projeto", "Extent1"."fk_usuario" FROM "public"."tb_atividade" AS "Extent1" WHERE "Extent1"."pk_atividade" = ((4)) LIMIT 2) AS "Alias1"
```

A mensagem da exceção:

```
ERROR: 42703: column Extent1.CodigoProjeto does not exist
```

PS: Estou utilizando PostgreSQL.

Comment: Eu queria entender por que você faz questão de mudar os nomes das colunas no banco.

Comment: Existe um padrão de nomenclatura para o banco de dados, e estou trabalhando com migração de um sistema que já está em produção com ADO.NET (sql puro).

Comment: Não usar *Fluent API* é uma opção?

Comment: Não é viável. Como é uma migração, fica mais simples isolar o código que tem essa responsabilidade. Não é viável carregar os modelos com mais anotações.

Comment: Mas pq não usar Fluent API ? Ele não pode resolver essa particularide?

Comment: Pode, mas não resolve alguns casos muito bem. Vou pensar em uma resposta. Preciso dos *Models* no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Pronto, foram incluídos. Desconsidere as propriedades de acesso, não estão sendo utilizadas (pontes para Projeto.Codigo, por exemplo). Poderia explicar mais sobre 'mas não resolve alguns casos muito bem' ? Quais são as situações?

Comment: Situações de associação direta, associação indireta, mapeamentos e nomes, enfim. Seus *Models* estão bastante fora do padrão do Entity Framework, então a chance de não funcionar é bem grande. Qual o comando usado para executar a *query* que levanta `Exception`?

Comment: Bem, estou fazendo provas de conceito em relação ao EF, para concluir sobre a viabilidade ou não de sua utilização neste projeto. Meu objetivo é utilizar um framework ORM a priore. Terei modelos das mais diversas formas possíveis, com estratégias de polimorfirsmo (interfaces) por exemplo. Estou incluindo oq você solicitou à pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos começar pelo SQL gerado:

```sql
SELECT "Alias1"."status_atividade", "Alias1"."pk_atividade",
"Alias1"."data_hora_fim", "Alias1"."data_hora_inicio",
"Alias1"."descricao_atividade", "Alias1"."estimativa_inicial_atividade",
"Alias1"."CodigoProjeto", "Alias1"."CodigoUsuario",
"Alias1"."tipo_atividade", "Alias1"."titulo_atividade",
"Alias1"."fk_projeto", "Alias1"."fk_usuario" FROM 
    (SELECT "Extent1"."pk_atividade", "Extent1"."data_hora_fim",
    "Extent1"."data_hora_inicio", "Extent1"."descricao_atividade",
    "Extent1"."estimativa_inicial_atividade", "Extent1"."CodigoProjeto", 
    "Extent1"."CodigoUsuario", "Extent1"."status_atividade",
    "Extent1"."tipo_atividade", "Extent1"."titulo_atividade",
    "Extent1"."fk_projeto", "Extent1"."fk_usuario" 
    FROM "public"."tb_atividade" AS "Extent1" 
    WHERE "Extent1"."pk_atividade" = ((4)) LIMIT 2) AS "Alias1"
```

Repare que em nenhum momento você referencia `CodigoProjeto` e `CodigoUsuario` aqui:

```
    public AtividadeMap()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.Codigo);

        ToTable("tb_atividade");

        Property(a => a.TituloAtividade).HasColumnName("titulo_atividade");
        Property(a => a.DescricaoAtividade).HasColumnName("descricao_atividade");
        Property(a => a.DataHoraInicio).HasColumnName("data_hora_inicio");
        Property(a => a.DataHoraFim).HasColumnName("data_hora_fim");
        Property(a => a.Codigo).HasColumnName("pk_atividade");
        Property(a => a.StatusAtividade.Identificador).HasColumnName("status_atividade");
        Property(a => a.EstimativaInicialAtividade).HasColumnName("estimativa_inicial_atividade");
        Property(a => a.TipoAtividade.Identificador).HasColumnName("tipo_atividade");

        HasRequired(a => a.Usuario)
       .WithMany()
       .Map(e => e.MapKey("fk_usuario"));

        HasRequired(a => a.Projeto)
       .WithMany()
       .Map(e => e.MapKey("fk_projeto"));

    }
```

Obviamente não vai funcionar. Como as duas propriedades não fazem parte da consulta (porque não são campos de dados, e sim, propriedades de navegação que você mesmo definiu), você precisa marcar essas propriedades com `[NotMapped]` para retirar as colunas da consulta.

```
    [NotMapped]
    public long CodigoProjeto {
        get
        {
            return Projeto.Codigo;
        }
        set
        {
            Projeto.Codigo = value;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public long CodigoUsuario {
        get
        {
            if(Usuario == null) Usuario = new Usuario();
            return Usuario.Codigo;
        }
        set
        {
            Usuario.Codigo = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Irei fazer a modificação Cigano, mas dai lhe pergunto, o mapeamento no Fluent-API não tem o objetivo de explicitar quais propriedades estou trabalhando no contexto de persistência? Faltou eu definir alguma configuração no meu DBContext para orientá-lo a utilizar apenas o que está mapeado?

Comment: Realmente não analisei a fundo o SQL gerado, ele está gerando o fk_usuario e fk_projeto perfeitamente, mas está gerando também o 'CodigoUsuario' e 'CodigoProjeto'. É exatamente isso. Preciso definir então uma configuração que diga ao EF  que, só quero que ele trabalhe com o que está mapeado na classe de EntityTypeConfiguration? Irei pesquisar agora. Porque como citei, estou em processo de migração, com os modelos já implementados. Definir as propriedades que não devem ser mapeadas, uma a uma, será um retrocesso. Também posso ignorar todas as propriedades via reflexão, mas ficaria ruim.

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães O mapeamento mais recomendado, aí falando por experiência, é o de atributos, em que você decora as propriedades do *Model* em questão. O `[NotMapped]` é um bom exemplo disso. Usar a *Fluent API* pra configurar tudo se torna um tanto prolixo num estágio mais avançado de desenvolvimento. No seu caso, as configurações já estão definidas de acordo, e o que ocorre é que o SQL gerado é um comportamento padrão do Entity Framework: ele deduz que cada propriedade existe em banco, sem necessariamente conferir a implementação delas. Você chegou a testar conforme a resposta?

Comment: Sim, funcionou. Porém fiquei decepcionado pelo fato de que, como já estou explicitando *cada* propriedade, esperasse que o EF não 'tomasse decisões por conta própria'.

Comment: Estou esperando apenas uma resposta sobre o contexto da pergunta para concluí-la: Existe uma propriedade que defina que o EF **utilize apenas as propriedades mapeadas na minha classe de configuração EntityTypeConfiguration**?

Comment: Sobre utilizar FluentAPI ou anotações, bem, acho que teria que te passar bastante detalhes sobre o projeto e iria estender bastante o assunto, talvez fugir do contexto desta pergunta. Me parece que existe um recurso de CHAT , caso esteja interessado posso lhe descrever por lá.

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc